# Wordpress older version installation

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

For learning purpose I want to install the old version of WordPress i.e (v0.7 or v1.0). But Older version of WordPress needs an older version of PHP and mysql i.e (PHP4 (version 4.0.6 or higher), MySQL (version 3.23.23 or higher)). How can I do that? I am using windows 8.1

Thanks in advance

Comment: Just in case you're not aware of this: you should not use an older version of WordPress for a public facing website, as it will be insecure.

Comment: I'd suggest reading up on Vagrant. You can setup a server locally with any configuration you like.

Comment: For learning purpose also you can download the latest version and try or learn on it, why would you like to go with older version, not a good idea though.

Comment: Thank you for your replies, JonasCz I just want to use it locally.

Comment: @Anup GC Yes, you are right, I can use the latest version of PHP, etc., but the problem is an older version of Wordpress like version 0.7 it's not working with latest version edition of php